# How to blur the background of new added view on frame layout?Android

Tags: android, android-layout, blur

I am searching for it from very long time. I want to blur the background of the new added view to the frame layout. The new added view is a linear layout which opens as a pop up. Now how can I blur that frame layout.

I have gone through all the posts regarding blurring the background but i did not find that useful for my problem Because they all suggest to create a bitmap and set it blur on the bitmap. I simply want to blur the complete view behind the pop up

Comment: have you try this https://github.com/faradaj/BlurBehind

Comment: @Ravi  compile ` 'com.faradaj:blur-behind:[LATEST_RELEASE_VERSION]'` what is the latest release version i cannot find it anywhere

Comment: import library that avible there or try any number of value, as like 1,2

Comment: it is written like this in example of github repo compile project(':blur-behind') but this is not compiling in my project

Comment: See below my answer that can help you..

Answer (score 1):

Use this library to blur the background of popup https://github.com/faradaj/BlurBehind

On BlurredActivity show the popup and finish the activity when pop dismiss.

Comment: compile 'com.faradaj:blur-behind:[LATEST_RELEASE_VERSION]' what is the latest release version i cannot find it anywhere

Answer (score 1):

You can use Renderscript Intrinsics, which are a set of built-in functions that require very little code to use, but are optimized for high-performance.

Once you have the blurring, the rest of the process is fairly straight forward. When you plan to leave an activity, create a bitmap of the current view and write it to disk. When you start your new activity (which should have a transparent background), you override the transition (otherwise you’ll get the default zoom), and set the background to the blurred image you saved earlier. Add a fade in for the alpha and you get a nice little effect!

[image: Blur view]

**If you’d like to see how this looks in a sample project, you can find it on Github [here](https://github.com/MichaelEvans/EtsyBlurExample).**